# How to make a Junit Test in java with scanner and exception

Tags: java, junit

I tried to do a JUNIT test to my method but i can't get any result.

```
public int withDrowMoney() {
    enterAmount = scann.nextInt();

    if (enterAmount <= 10) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your enterAmount is too low");

    } else if (enterAmount >= 10000) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Your enterAmount is too high");

    } else if (enterAmount % 100 != 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("You must take 100 200 and so on");

    } else if (inMemoryAtm.getAllLastWithDrow().isEmpty()) {
        NEWBALANCE = account.getAccountBalance() - enterAmount;
        inMemoryAccount.saveNewBalance(NEWBALANCE);
    } else {
        NEWBALANCE = inMemoryAccount.getSaveNewBalance().get(0) - enterAmount;
        inMemoryAccount.saveNewBalance(NEWBALANCE);

    }
    inMemoryAtm.saveLastWithDrow(enterAmount);
    return NEWBALANCE;

}
```

Comment: can any one help mig with that I'm new in java

Comment: Please show your current attempt at the unit test.

Comment: @Test public void canWithDrowMoney(){assertNotNull(atm.wittDrowMoney);}

Comment: 1) You're not calling the method there. You need to make a method call, like any other code. 2) `int` (autoboxed to `Integer`) can never be null, so the test would never fail. 3) Put code in your question, not in comments. [Edit] your question to add it.

Comment: And hint: it source  code violates multiple "good practices" for java code. It seems that you dont have **any** local variables there, all things are fields in your class. Why?! Then ALL_UPPERCASE is for constants (!) only. I am pretty sure that NEWBALANCE is not a constant. And naming is also kinda bad ... enterAmount ... what about "amountToWithdraw" ?!